# Parse object from sql

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I've created the table and put several rows into it. Is there a way to parse my own objects from table?

```
class Human
{
    string name;
    int age;

    public Human(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

-- create table    
string sql = "create table human (name varchar(20), age int)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

-- insert sample data
string sql = "insert into human (name, age) values ('John', 20)";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

-- get the data back from that table
string sql = "select * from human";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
```

Now how do I parse a `Human` instance from my reader?

Comment: Also: in your last query, **do not** call `.ExecuteQuery()` after you've already called `.EXecuteReader`! Just one call, please - and since you want to get back the result set, you need `.ExecuteReader()` ....

Comment: @marc_s It's a sample for the question, it's not a real code, but anyway - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can**

Its very simple infact.
Try this:

```
//Create Collection of Human to store the values
List<Human> Humans = new List<Human>();
while (reader.Read())
{
   //Create Human Object from Sql Reader
   Human h=new Human(reader.getString(0),reader.getInt(1));
   //Add the object to collection
   Humans.add(h);
}
```

Humans Will have all the Human Object you get as rows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. I would suggest using **[Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx)** which essentially allows you to bind types in your code to tables in the database.

For SQLite, here are a couple of links to get you started:

http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html

http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html

Comment: This might make a more useful comment--the asker was really wondering about how to get data out of that data reader, which they've set up. EF is *sometimes* a better option, for some situations, and it's probably worth bringing up, but it's not really an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: My project is little not really complex, with no resterictions on time or speed, so I don't really need to complicate it more with framework. Still thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks @MatthewHaugen for the advice - in hindsight, I agree. XSIon, you're welcome.